# Application runs in development but in .exe gives error

Tags: python, compilation, pyinstaller, exe, python-tesseract

I have created an application that takes a print of the screen and copies the text of the print to the clipboard.

It is working perfectly in development, however when I use `pyinstaller` to compile, the .exe file gives the following error.

[image error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tcIbp.png)

"Traceback (most recent call last):
File "logging_*init*_.py", line 1113, in emit
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write'"

im using `pyinstaller -w .\main.py` to compile

```
import pyautogui
import pytesseract
import cv2
import keyboard
from pyperclip import copy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder

screenshot_url = r"C:\\Users\\Public\\Pictures\\screenshot_1.png"


def img_to_string():
    image = cv2.imread(screenshot_url)
    path = r"C:\\Program Files\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe"
    pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = path
    return pytesseract.image_to_string(image)


def cut_image():
    try:
        im = cv2.imread(screenshot_url)
        roi = cv2.selectROI(im)
        im_cropped = im[int(roi[1]):int(roi[1] + roi[3]), 
                        int(roi[0]):int(roi[0] + roi[2])]
        cv2.imwrite(screenshot_url, im_cropped)
        image_in_string = img_to_string()
        copy(image_in_string)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error: {e}")
    finally:
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()


def screenshot_from_app():
    screenshot = pyautogui.screenshot()
    screenshot.save(screenshot_url)


class myApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_file("screen.kv")
    
    def on_start(self):
        ss_button = self.root.ids["ss-button"]
    
        def on_press_button(arg):
            screenshot_from_app()
            cut_image()
    
        def on_press_key():
            screenshot_from_app()
            cut_image()
    
        ss_button.bind(on_press=on_press_button)
    
        keyboard.add_hotkey("ctrl+[", on_press_key)

myApp().run()
```

I'm not experienced in python, but I know how to program, I already looked for the error in chatGPT and in videos on youtube, but I don't find my specific problem

I just need the application to run in an executable